# It doesn't work to upload a file in PHP

Tags: php, html, file-upload, image-uploading

[image: File form myupload.html]

[image: File: uploadfile.php]

It doesn't work to  upload a file. Please help me!

Comment: You should paste your code into the question in text and not as an image. This will enable the experts to reproduce your fault and provide you with help; otherwise they might just ignore you. You can use the [edit] button to add that code. Then we can help.

Comment: You should also elaborate on "It doesn't work", as that could describe hundreds of different errors/scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Form uploadfile.html

```
<form action="uploadfile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image upload
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Image Upload">
```

_File uploadfile.php

```
$upload_dir ="/uploads";
foreach ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error ==UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name =basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$key]);
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$upload_dir/$name");
    }
}
```

_Don't enable upload any file.